# How to get jQuery to apply class to first td in a row

Tags: jquery

I currently have a table which is a while loop from the results in my database. In my table row it contains a value which will be + or - amount of days. I am trying to create a jQuery script which will find out if the td contains("-") or ("+") and I want it to apply a css style to the first td of that row. At the moment it applies it to every first td in **all** rows.

```
        $("tr td:nth-child(7):contains('+')").each(function() {
    $('tr td:first-child').css('background-color', 'blue');
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$(this)` so that you are referring to "this" element in the loop.

Then as "this" is the `td` element, find the parent `tr`, and then find the `first-child` nested within that element.

```
$("tr td:nth-child(7):contains('+')").each(function() {
    $(this).parent("tr").find('td:first-child').css('background-color', 'blue');
});
```

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g7ZTf/

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this...

```
$(function(){
    $("tr td:nth-child(7):contains('+')").each(function() {
        // get a jQuery object of the selected element using `$(this)`
        // then select `.siblings()`, and limit to first element in array (`.eq(0)`)
        $(this).siblings().eq(0).css('background-color', 'blue');
    });
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FqUB3/